# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jakarta-ee, javax

The error I am getting comes out as this:

> `javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created    at
>   javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:370)
>     at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:313)  at
>   javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:227)   at
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:154)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.JaxbProcessor.buildStaxFactory(JaxbProcessor.java:107)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.JaxbProcessor.staxFactory(JaxbProcessor.java:100)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.JaxbProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbProcessor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.service.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:69)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.mergePropertySources(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:549)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:214)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:131)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:93)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:101)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:69)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
>     at
>   org.capgemini.test.RoutingPointTest3.setUpBeforeClass(RoutingPointTest3.java:33)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created    at
>   javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:367)
>     ... 35 more Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider
>   com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found  at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)  at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)    at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)   at
>   javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:353)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:341)
>     ... 35 more
>
> `

I tried to do a test of my class routingpoint here is the code:

```
public class RoutingPointTest3 {
     private static EntityManager em;
     private static
     EntityManagerFactory emf;  
     private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "sample";


     @BeforeClass   
     public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
     }

     @Test  
     public void test() {
            EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            RoutingPoint rp = new RoutingPoint();       
            rp.setRoutingPoint(0753);
            em.persist(rp);
            tx.commit();
            long id = rp.getId();
            assertNotNull("Id not null", id);
            em.close();
            RoutingPoint rp2 = em.find(RoutingPoint.class, id);         
            assertNotNull("routing point from database", rp2);  
     }

}
```

Comment: please help me to debug this error, i already do anythings but it doesnt work, and i don't know why please

Comment: `com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory` do you have the library that contains this class in your classpath? ` org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl ` probably?

Comment: i don't have this librabry, i going to put that in my dependancies

Comment: i add this library and i have this error :

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.build(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:214)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1035)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)

Comment: Your problem is dependencies. You are clearly using conflicting versions of your dependencies.